# Compound query on Firebase 9 (modular)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I have an Expo project where I need to do this query:

```
const queryEvents = query(
    colRef,
    where('neighborhood', 'in', neighbors),
    where('curfew', '<', end)
);
```

Where 'neighbors' is a geohash array and 'end' is a timestamp. So far, with the first condition it works fine but whenever I put in the second one, firebase throws this error:

> @firebase/firestore:, Firestore (9.9.2): Uncaught Error in snapshot listener:, {"code":"failed-precondition","name":"FirebaseError"}

For what I read, there are some limitations as to querying different fields with different operators, however in the documentation, there is an example of 'valid range' query, but such example is just two different queries, as I'm pretty new to firestore/firebase so I wonder if 'q1' and 'q2' can be used in my onSnapshot call. Heres's the given example:

```
import { query, where } from "firebase/firestore";  

const q1 = query(citiesRef, where("state", ">=", "CA"), where("state", "<=", "IN"));
const q2 = query(citiesRef, where("state", "==", "CA"), where("population", ">", 1000000));
```

Per a comment suggestion, here's the snapshot:

```
    const getEvents = async (dbx) => {
    
        let end = new Date(Date.now() + ( 3600 * 1000 * 25 ));
        console.log("Date: ", end)
        const colRef = collection(dbx, 'events');
        const queryEvents = query(colRef, where('neighborhood', 'in', neighbors));
        onSnapshot(queryEvents, 
                (snapshot)=>{
                    let evs = [];
                    snapshot.docs.forEach((doc)=>{
                        evs.push({...doc.data(), key: doc.id})
                    })
                    setEvents(evs)
                    return evs;
                });
      }

Per another contributor's request, here's the package.json:

{
  "name": "cartelera",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^15.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^15.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^15.3.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.4.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.11",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.7.0",
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-location": "~14.2.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "firebase": "^9.9.2",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "geofire": "^6.0.0",
    "geohashes-near": "^2.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.2.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.11.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": ">= 6.x.x",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.10"
  },
  "private": true,
  "react-native-dynamic-vector-icons": "WrathChaos/react-native-dynamic-vector-icons#expo"
```

}

Comment: The error message says there's a problem with a snapshot listener, but you're not showing any listeners here.

Comment: It sounds like you didn't add a composite index for the `neighborhood`/`curfew` combination.

Comment: I added the composite index and didn't work either

Comment: Haven't you received any warning in the console like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdzi4.png)? You have to create the composite index from the link produced by the warning.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I read, however, no link was provided in the warning

Comment: Could you provide more info regarding the issue you're dealing with like package.json. I tried to reproduce the given code above but it gives me a link to create a composite index.

Comment: For sure, there it is the package.json file.

Comment: I already tried to reproduce but unfortunately, I'm not able to reproduce the error you've encountered. I'm always getting the warning with a link provided instead. I would suggest to contact [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support) to help you further.

Comment: Thank you, I already contacted FIrebase Support, your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the composite index error was indeed the problem, I wasn't getting the link to set it up. I did contact support on Google but they didn't had an answer either.
I resorted to uninstall and reinstall Firestore but that didn't worked until I uninstalled and reinstalled Firebase, however, if I only executed

```
%yarn add firebase
```

of

```
%npm install firebase
```

Wasn't enough, I had to expressively use

```
% npm install firebase@9.6.11
```

Once done that, I restarted the project, the link to build the composite index appeared and now it's all working fine.